# Conditional Expectation with Respect to "Y" as a Polynomial in "Y"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I was reading on conditional expectation online when I came to this curious passage:
[image: passage]

I can easily understand that
$\mathbb E[X|Y]$ can be seen as a *function of* $Y$:
for any $\omega\in\Omega$ in the underlying sample space,
the value of $\mathbb E[X|Y](\omega)$ is obtained from $Y$ through
$$\mathbb E[X|Y](\omega)=\mathbb E[X|Y(\omega)].$$

What baffles me though is the claim that if $Y$ is a simple random variable,
i.e.,
can be written as
$$Y=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\chi_{A_i},$$
where $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are constants and $A_1,\ldots,A_n$
are measurable and disjoint,
then $\mathbb E[X|Y]$ is a *polynomial* function of $Y$.
In the simplest case when
$Y=x1_A$ for some measurable set $A$ and constant $X$,
one easily shows that
$$\mathbb E[X|Y]=\mathbb E[X|Y=0]+\left(\frac{\mathbb E[X|Y=x]-\mathbb E[X|Y=0]}x\right)Y.$$

However,
as soon as $Y$ can take up to three distinct values (including $0$),
I have absolutely no idea how to proceed.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose in the case of $n=3$ you could write it as
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y=a_1] \frac{(Y-a_2)(Y-a_3)}{(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)}+\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y=a_2] \frac{(Y-a_1)(Y-a_3)}{(a_2-a_1)(a_2-a_3)}\\
&\qquad+\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y=a_3] \frac{(Y-a_1)(Y-a_2)}{(a_3-a_1)(a_3-a_2)},
\end{align*}
and you can use the same pattern for higher $n$.

I don't really see any advantage in writing it in this way, though.