# Approximation of Conditional Expectation with Respect to "Y" Using Simple Approximation of "Y"

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, lp-spaces, conditional-expectation

**Background.**
(TL:DR you can skip to **Question.** below.)
This is a followup question to one of my previous questions ([linked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068592/conditional-expectation-with-respect-to-y-as-a-polynomial-in-y)) on this website.

In short,
the other question was about how to express the conditional expectation with respect to a simple random variable $Y$ in terms of a polynomial in $Y$.
More specifically,
suppose that $Y$ can be written as
\begin{align}\tag{1}
Y=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\chi_{A_i},
\end{align}
where the $A_i$ partition the sample space into sets of positive measure.
Then,
given any random variable $X$,
one has
\begin{align}\tag{2}\mathbb E\big[X \, \big| \, Y\big]=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\mathbb E\big[X \, \big| \, Y=a_i\big]\prod_{j\neq i}\frac{(Y-a_j)}{(a_i-a_j)}\right).\end{align}

After providing an answer to my question,
[angryavian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43949/angryavian) questioned the usefulness of writing the conditional expectation in those terms.

After thinking about it for some time,
I had an idea:
Given that,
in any $L^p$ space,
a random variable $Y$ may be approximated in the $\|\cdot\|_{p}$ by *simple* random variables (i.e., random variables that can be written as a sum like equation $(1)$),
maybe one could approximate the random variable $\mathbb E\big[X \, \big| \,  Y\big]$ using the polynomials
$$\mathbb E\big[X \, \big| \, Y_n\big]=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\mathbb E\big[X \, \big| \, Y_n=a_i\big]\prod_{j\neq i}\frac{(Y_n-a_j)}{(a_i-a_j)}\right),$$
where $\{Y_n\}_n$ is a sequence of simple random variables that converges to $Y$ in a suitably chosen $L^p$-norm.

This then leads me to the following question:

---

**Question.** If $Y_n$ converges to $Y$ in distribution, in probability, almost surely,
or with respect to some $L^p$ norm,
then does $\mathbb E\big[X \, \big| \, Y_n\big]$ also converge to $\mathbb E\big[X \, \big| \, Y\big]$ in distribution, in probability, almost surely,
or with respect to some $L^p$ norm?

Every convergence result I have seen with conditional expectation is about $\mathbb E[X_n \mid Y]\to\mathbb E[X_n \mid Y]$ where $X_n\to X$,
not the other way around.

Furthermore,
given that $\mathbb E[X \mid Y]$ is actually defined as $\mathbb E[X \mid \mathcal A]$,
where $\mathcal A$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$,
I'm having trouble imagining what a statement like

> $\mathbb E[X \mid \mathcal A_n]\to\mathbb E[X \mid \mathcal A]$ when $\mathcal A_n\to\mathcal A$

should mean,
given that I'm not aware of any convergence concepts for $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: $E[X|\mathcal{A}_n]$ and $E[X|\mathcal{A}]$ are random variables, so you're talking about convergence in distribution.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Right. The part that perplexes me is $\mathcal A_n\to\mathcal A$.

Comment: An intuitive way to think about it is that $\mathcal A_n\to\mathcal A := \mathcal A_n \Delta \mathcal A \to \emptyset$

Comment: Also: here's a great paper on just your question: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176988743 .. from Annals of Probability no less!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference, I will look this up!

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{A}:=\sigma\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathcal{A}_n\right)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra that contains all the $\sigma$-algebras: $\mathcal{A}_1,\mathcal{A}_2,\dots$ so there is really no general "convergence" of $\sigma$-algebras.